# How can I test react-native component with mocha + enzyme + chai when it's wrapped in a Provider component

Tags: testing, react-native, mocha.js, mockery, enzyme

I'm using **mocha, enzyme, chai** and some mocking libraries to make the testing possible. So, the content of **TestComponent.js** is below, I configure the store and pass it to the provider, while **DeskScreen** is connected component:

```
import mockery from "mockery";
import 'babel-polyfill';
import reactNativeSvgMock from "react-native-svg-mock";
mockery.enable();
mockery.registerMock("react-native-svg", reactNativeSvgMock);
var DeskScreen = require( '../app/containers/DeskScreen/DeskScreen');
import React, {View, Text, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import {shallow, render, mount} from 'enzyme';
import {expect} from 'chai';
import configureStore from 'redux-mock-store';
import reducer from "../app/reducers";
import Button from "../app/containers/Common/Button";
import ButtonWithNoFlex from "../app/containers/Common/ButtonWithNoFlex";
const mockStore = configureStore([]);

describe('<Test />', () => {
    it('it should render 1 view component', () => {
        const store = mockStore(reducer);
        var comp = shallow(
         <Provider store={store}>
            <DeskScreen/>
        </Provider>
    );
        expect(button).to.have.length(1);
        expect(comp.find(View)).to.have.length(1);
    });
});
```

After running the command npm test it produces the following:

```
1) it should render 1 view component


  0 passing (1s)
  1 failing

  1) <Test /> it should render 1 view component:
     AssertionError: expected { Object (root, unrendered, ...) } to have a length of 1 but got 0
      at Context.<anonymous> (test/TestComponent.js:22:41)
```

Maybe the reason is I use the shallow instead of mount, but as I know mount is not available for react-native. Anyway, I'd like to test connected component somehow.

Answer (score 2):

I think there are two ways to use solve the problem.

## 1. Export plain component

In your component file export the component as named export which you can use in your tests.

```
// Export the plain component as named component
export class MyComponent {
    // ...
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(MyComponent);
```

Your test import the plain compenent via named import:

```
import { MyComponent } from './MyComponent';

// Use it in your tests
```

## 2. Provide context via `shallow`

You can use the connected component if you provide the store via context. This is what `<Provider>` does.

```
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import { createStore } from 'redux';

// reducer could be a real reducer or a mock fake reducer.
const store = createStore(reducer);

it('my test', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(
        <MyComponent>,
        { context: { store } }
    );

    // test your component here
});
```

Comment: Mad props on your *2. Provide context via shallow* -- helped me tons!